# Dataset in Mathematica 10.0.1

Tags: version-10, dataset, associations

Wolfram pages ["Mathematica Quick Revision History"](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html) in Mathematica 10.0.1 release says:

> "New operators and compositions of operators enabled for associations
>   functions such as Dataset and Query"

What are these news? Some place where I can find more information about it?

Comment: These are now documented on the Wolfram website: [Dataset\[\]](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) [Query\[\]](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html)

Comment: @Murta, are you still looking for an answer? Release logs are ususally only skin deep but to claim that authoritatively one needs to be from WRI.